# Why does PowerMock try to load some classes, which are used in non-mocking class method?

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermock

I use JUnit4 with Mockito for Unit Testing, and now I'm trying to add PowerMock into my toolbox.
And at once I'm facing a weird class loading behaviour of PowerMock. So, I use some code like that:

```
@PrepareForTest(ClassToMock.class)
public class MyTest
{
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception
    {
        // some test code using ClassToMock
        MyHelper.staticMethod(param);
        // some other test code
    }
}
```

MyHelper is some class from another bundle, and staticMethod() is some method, which I don't need to be mocked. This method uses Google Gson and some my serializers (let's say - MySerializer class).
And PowerMock throws me a javassist.NotFoundException for Google Gson and MySerializer.
For example:

```
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:450)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:220)
```

I can add those classes to the classpath (to the Impored-Packages), but I don't want to. And why does PowerMock try to load classes, which are used inside some method, which supposed to be just a "black box", at the first place?

Can anyone explain that, please?

Also, I can get rid of loading Gson using @PowerMockIgnore("com.google.*") annotation, but it doesn't work for MySerializer. And it doesn't seem like a proper solution anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: No, seriously, why does it try to use its own classloader for **everything**?  
When I just instantiate some class MyClass (it isn't needed to be mocked) PowerMock tries to load **every** dependency of MyClass, all classes which present MyClass methods arguments or return types.  
But I haven't even call a single method!

Comment: your classes might be using static blocks, which needs to be suppressed using powermock, so that it does not go and load all the required classes by those static blocks

Answer (score 0):

your classes might be using

> static blocks

which needs to be suppressed using **powermock**, so that it does not go and load all the required classes by those static blocks

[refer this link to see the usage of SuppressUnwantedBehavior](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior)